# How to move an Oval to the coordinates of the mouseClick?

Tags: java, oop, jframe, jpanel, mouseclick-event

I am trying to build a little program in Java OOP, that will display an oval that changes its position to mouse click coordinates. However, as I am a beginner I dont know how to finish it.

Does anyone know what is wrong on my program?

```
public class OvalWindow {

 JFrame window;
 int windowWidth = 500;
 int windowHeight = 500;

 OvalPanel panel;

   public void run() {
      //Set a window
      window = new JFrame("Oval moving");
      window.setVisible(true);
      window.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    

      //Create a panel and add it to the window
      panel = new OvalPanel();
      window.setContentPane(panel);

      //Change the location on mouse input
      panel.addMouseListener(new OvalMouseClick(panel));


   }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    OvalWindow oWndow = new OvalWindow();
    oWndow.run();
  }

}
```

File: Oval.java 
Create an Oval class

```
 public class Oval {

        private int diameter;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private Color color;

        public Oval(int x, int y, int diameter, Color color) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.diameter = diameter;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }
        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }
        public int getDiameter() {
            return diameter;
        }
        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        /*
         * Draw the oval 
         */
        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            g.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
            g.setColor(color);

        }
}
```

File: OvalPanel.java
This class add objects ovals to the screen.
Also, sets the initial position of the oval

```
    public class OvalPanel extends JPanel{
     Oval oval;

     public void addOval(Oval oval) {
     oval = new Oval(100, 100, 50, Color.BLACK);
     this.repaint();

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        oval.draw(g);
    }


  }
```

File: OvalMouseClick.java
This class add a new oval to the screen, at the same position as the mouse clicked coordinates.

```
    public class OvalMouseClick extends MouseAdapter{
        OvalPanel panel;

        public OvalMouseClick(OvalPanel panel) {
            this.panel = panel;
        }


        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            panel.addOval(new Oval(e.getX(), e.getY(), 50, Color.BLUE));

        }

    }
```

Comment: What have you edited @pfx? Cuz I dont see the changes.

Comment: Just a typo in the title :) “I ma ...” to “I am ...”. You are free to undo if you want to.

Comment: Pasting a slab of code and saying "something's wrong" is not a good way to get help. You need to tell us what's wrong.

Comment: The code does not display an oval at the coordinates of the mouseClick

Comment: Well, you never seem to call `Oval.draw()` anywhere for one. Presumably you'd call that in `OvalPanel.paintComponent()`, but you haven't implemented it.

Comment: @Kayaman , would't be paintComponent() the same as   


          
           public void  draw(Graphics g) {
  g.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
  g.setColor(color);

     }

Comment: No, because when you call `repaint()` the individual components (such as `JPanel` and its subclasses) are processed and their `paintComponent()` is called. Your `OvalPanel` hasn't overridden the method, so it will be painted just like a normal empty `JPanel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is looking for the answer. Here is my solution:

I have modified the file: OvalWindow.java

```
        public class OvalWindow {

            JFrame window;
            OvalPanel panel;

            int windowWidth = 500;
            int windowHeight = 500;

            /**
             * Run the program
             */
            public void run() {
                // Set a window
                window = new JFrame("Oval moving");
                window.setVisible(true);
                window.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                // Create a panel and add it to the window
                panel = new OvalPanel();
                window.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        panel.moveToCoord(e);
                    }
                });

            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                OvalWindow oWndow = new OvalWindow();
                oWndow.run();
            }

        }
```

I have also significantly  modified the file: OvalPanel.java

```
        public class OvalPanel extends JPanel {
            Oval oval;
            int x = 50;
            int y = 10;
            int diameter = 50;
            Color color = Color.BLUE;

            public void moveToCoord(MouseEvent e) {
                x = e.getX() - diameter / 2;
                y = e.getY() - diameter / 2;
                repaint();

            }

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                oval = new Oval(x, y, diameter, color);
                oval.draw(g);

            }

        }
```

On the file: Oval.java was only a small change:

```
 public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);

}
```

The file: OvalMouseClick.java was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom `paintComponent()` method to make your `OvalPanel` actually display something. If you added components to it, they would be displayed automatically, but your `Oval` class is not a component (in the UI sense) so you'll need to explicitly write the code to display them.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    for(Oval o : ovals)
        o.draw(g);
}
```

I also recommend reading the Swing trail at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ because you can't just "guess" how things work. Swing is complex, and you need to understand what it does. Then you'll realize that `draw(Graphics g)` and `paintComponent(Graphics g)` are more than similar methods with a different name.

Comment: that indeed helped me to display the oval on the window @Kayaman, but I think I need to find a way to delete the old one, as I want to move the position not to add many ovals to the panel.

Comment: Then why do you have a list of Ovals instead of a single `Oval`? The list would indicate that the panel can contain multiple ovals.

Comment: because I dont know how to store a single oval. I know is stupid, but i just dont know :(

Comment: You know how to store a single `OvalPanel`, you know how to store a single `Color` and so on. Unless you didn't write the code you're showing?

Comment: I know some stuff, but obviously I am not understanding completely how it works yet.  I also got inspired from internet.